# If else statement inside a for loop[java]

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, coding-style, open-closed-principle

I have some code like this, converting Sting to objects. But it includes if statement inside for loop, to indicate the first node and last node. Is there any better coding than this?

```
splitQueue = "Man-1/Man-2/Man-3/Man-4".split("/");
QueueSplitLen = splitQueue.length;
Queue[] manArray = new Queue[QueueSplitLen];
for (int i = 0; i < QueueSplitLen; i++) {

    // first Man, no parent Queue
    if (i == 0) {
        Man newMan = new Man(splitQueue[0]);
        manArray[0] = new Queue(newMan, null);

        // last Man, be current Man
    } else if (i == QueueSplitLen - 1) {
        this.curMan = new Man(splitQueue[i]);
        this.parentQueue = manArray[i - 1];

        // one's parent is the previous one.
    } else {
        Man newMan = new Man(splitQueue[i]);
        manArray[i] = new Queue(newMan, manArray[i - 1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not storing storing the last `Man` to the `manArray`?

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the first and last node outside the loop :

```
    // first
    Man newMan = new Man(splitQueue[0]);
    manArray[0] = new Queue(newMan, null);
    // all the rest
    for (int i = 1; i < QueueSplitLen - 1; i++) {
        newMan = new Man(splitQueue[i]);
        manArray[i] = new Queue(newMan, manArray[i - 1]);
    }
    // last
    this.curMan = new Man(splitQueue[QueueSplitLen - 1]);
    this.parentQueue = manArray[QueueSplitLen - 2];
```

Of course this code assumes at least two elements in the array. If that's not the case, you must add some conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You could extract  the first and last chunks outside the `for` loop and leave the mid-section there. Obviously you will need to add other checks on the code you extract, mainly to ensure that you have at least 1 item (first `if` condition) and that you have more than 1 (last `if` condition).

```
    splitQueue = "Man-1/Man-2/Man-3/Man-4".split("/");
    QueueSplitLen = splitQueue.length;
    Queue[] manArray = new Queue[QueueSplitLen];

    if (manArray.length > 0) {
            Man newMan = new Man(splitQueue[0]);
            manArray[0] = new Queue(newMan, null);
            // last Man, be current Man
        }

    for (int i = 1; i < QueueSplitLen - 1; i++) {                       
            this.curMan = new Man(splitQueue[i]);
            this.parentQueue = manArray[i - 1];                
    }

    // one's parent is the previous one.
         if(manArray.length > 1) {
            Man newMan = new Man(splitQueue[manArray.length]);
            manArray[manArray.length] = new Queue(newMan, manArray[manArray.length - 2]);
        }
```

That being said, this might make the code slightly less readable, so it might be better to just leave it as is.

Answer (score 0):

One other option to code would be to use distinct methods for each of the cases, like:

```
retrieveManFromQueue(splitQueue);
retrieveLastManFromQueue(splitQueue);
retrieveOther(splitQueue);
```

Of course, this will require some "fine tuning" in order to find a good way to store the "results" computed by each method.

Answer (score 0):

With this code:

```
String[] splitQueue = "Man-1/Man-2/Man-3/Man-4".split("/");

for( String elem: splitQueue ){
  System.out.println(elem);         
}
```

I get this result:

`Man-1
Man-2
Man-3
Man-4`

What is the actual purpose to have a different treatment for the first & last element as they will be at the same place in the new array.

```
String[] splitQueue = "Man-1/Man-2/Man-3/Man-4".split("/");
List<NewObject> myList = new ArrayList<newObject>();

for( String elem: splitQueue ){
  myList.add(new Object(elem));         
}
```

`myList.get(0)` is the first element
`muList.get(myList.size()-1)` is the last element

You should use the fact that you read your `String[]` by iterating on it, so the new list will be filled iteratively to.

Am I missing something where you could give us some precisions ?

I'm guessing you're using a kind of "sequenced" Collection(doesn't applied on Set)